# CSS, selecting all first level elements

Tags: jquery, css

I know you can use '*' to select all element and 'ul > li' to get all first level elements but is it possible to have something like this '> *' or an equivalent.

Here is what I try to achieve, my current code (using jQuery):

```
$( '<div/>' ).html( content ).find( '*' );
```

... this will get me everything. I'd like to get only first level elements using the code above.

*Sample HTML structure for 'content' would be:*

```
<p>Text <strong>bold</strong></p>
<div>...</div>
<h1>Text</h1>
<div>Text-only</div>
```

Comment: but you can use `> *` and you will get everything at the first level

Comment: I tried that one and it doesn't work, can you point me to an example usage?

Comment: maybe you can tell us what do you expect to select from your HTML structure

Comment: Perhaps you want `.children()`?

Comment: See the sample content structure, I don't want to get <strong>bold</strong> which is second level.

Comment: Your questions title says you want first level elements. Please edit your question with more examples to better reflect what you're trying to achieve. And clarify what you mean by "it didn't work" What result did you get?

Comment: so as I said you can simply use `> *` selector :)

Comment: Yes, `.children()` works for what I'm asking above; but that wasn't the issue with my code. Thank you. I found what I need to do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.children()`:

```js
console.log($(".test").children()); // will only get <p>, <div>, <h1>, and <div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<p>Text <strong>bold</strong></p>
<div>...</div>
<h1>Text</h1>
<div>Text-only</div>
</div>
```

This will return all the direct children of the parent.